# UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing change my TextField frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I got an weird issue. Please help me in this case.I had a bottom View which contain a TextField like this image

[image]
When I type text in textfield, I want my bottom view move above the keyboard and be like this:

[image]

However, after typing one character, my bottom view will move back to this previous position
[image]

I found out that whenever I set

```
self.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

my bottom view will move back to its previous position. 
This is my source code link: https://github.com/duythuc28/ProblemUITextField

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change observers from UIKeyboardDidShowNotification to UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and from UIKeyboardDidHideNotification to UIKeyboardWillHideNotification. Second: don't change view's frame. You have bottom view's constraint to bottom (equal to 0); create outlet for this constraint and in method keyboardWillShow set it equal to keyboard height and in keyboardWillHide to 0.

Comment: No way, using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification you can't get the keyboard size.

Comment: By the way, I have solved the problems by setting constraint to bottom instead of setting frame.But we have to use UIKeyboardDidShowNotification to get frame of the keyboard. Thanks so much

Comment: Actually, you can get keyboard size:

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSValue *frameValue = [notification userInfo][UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[notification userInfo][UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:[frameValue CGRectValue] fromView:nil];
    
    CGFloat height = keyboardFrame.size.height;
//here you have keyboard height; do other stuff
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

Answer (score 1):

You are using Autolayout, so you cannot set frame for the view. It should reset the constraint.

Or you can use third-party such as IQKeyboardManager to handle your keyboard event with worries free. IQKeyboardManager can be used in both ObjectiveC and Swift. It can also handle the appearance of the suggestion on keyboard (which I realize in your code that haven't handled yet) Here is the link: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager